# Hotkeys for Previous and Next call stack frames in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Visual Studio gives many navigation hotkeys:
<kbd>F8</kbd> for next item in current panel (search results, errors ...),
<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd> for bookmarks,
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> for going back and more.

There is one hotkey that I can't find, and I can't even find the menu-command for it, so I can't create the hotkey myself.

I don't know if such exist: Previous and Next call-stack frame.

I try not using the mouse when programming, but when I need to go back the stack, I must use it to double click the previous frame.

Anyone? How about a macro that does it?

Comment: OK. I can do it without the mouse. Sorry.
I can open the stack window, navigate with the arrow keys and press enter at the relevant frame.
But I believe that's not the best solution.

Comment: I think there is no way to accomplish this (VS 2008).

Answer (score 20):

I wrote 2 macros to gain it: `PreviousStackFrame` and `NextStackFrame` and assigned shortcuts to

```
Function StackFrameIndex(ByRef aFrames As EnvDTE.StackFrames, ByRef aFrame As EnvDTE.StackFrame) As Long
    For StackFrameIndex = 1 To aFrames.Count
        If aFrames.Item(StackFrameIndex) Is aFrame Then Exit Function
    Next
    StackFrameIndex = -1
End Function

Sub NavigateStack(ByVal aShift As Long)
    If DTE.Debugger.CurrentProgram Is Nothing Then
        DTE.StatusBar.Text = "No program is currently being debugged."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim ind As Long = StackFrameIndex(DTE.Debugger.CurrentThread.StackFrames, DTE.Debugger.CurrentStackFrame)
    If ind = -1 Then
        DTE.StatusBar.Text = "Stack navigation failed"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ind = ind + aShift
    If ind <= 0 Or ind > DTE.Debugger.CurrentThread.StackFrames.Count Then
        DTE.StatusBar.Text = "Stack frame index is out of range"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    DTE.Debugger.CurrentStackFrame = DTE.Debugger.CurrentThread.StackFrames.Item(ind)
    DTE.StatusBar.Text = "Stack frame index: " & ind & " of " & DTE.Debugger.CurrentThread.StackFrames.Count
End Sub

Sub PreviousStackFrame()
    NavigateStack(1)
End Sub

Sub NextStackFrame()
    NavigateStack(-1)
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm assuming this was for VS 2008 or 2010, and not relevant for 2012 or 2013 ?

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this problem with [AutoHotkey](http://www.ahkscript.org). I made this a few months ago.
Suppose you wanted to use Control+1 and Control+2 and that Control+Alt+C is bound to showing the Call Stack window:

```
^1::SendInput !^c{down}{enter}
^2::SendInput !^c{up}{enter}
```

It seems to work pretty well. If you aren't already using AutoHotkey to show Visual Studio who's boss, please give it a shot. Your question indicates that you would benefit greatly from it. It's a game changer. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think theres an explict next-frame / prev-frame key binding but heres what I do.

CTRL-ALT-C is already bound to "Debug.CallStack"
  This will focus you in the Call Stack Tool Window

Once focused in the Callstack window... Up & Down arrows will move you through the call stack frames

I've then bound

CTRL-C, CTRL-S to "DebuggerContextMenus.CallStackWindow.SwitchToFrame"
and
CTRL-C, CTRL-C to "DebuggerContextMenus.CallStackWindow.SwitchToCode"

both of which will take you back into the code window at the particular frame.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Huge thanks to @Oleg Svechkarenko for his answer that gave me a starting point in crafting this solution. Since modern versions of Visual Studio no longer have official macro support, this should drop in for those who use the [Visual Commander](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SergeyVlasov.VisualCommander) plugin, but probably can be easily adapted for any other macro extension.

Here is the code for the command, I created one for navigating up the call stack and one for navigating down with the same code except the parameter passed to `MoveStackIndex()`, then bound keyboard shortcuts to them:

```cs
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using System;

public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    enum MoveDirection
    {
        Up,
        Down,
    }

    private bool IsValidFrame(StackFrame frame)
    {
        string language = frame.Language;

        bool result = (language == "C#"  || 
                       language == "C++" || 
                       language == "VB"  || 
                       language == "Python");

        return result;
    }

    private void MoveStackIndex(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, MoveDirection direction)
    {
        StackFrame currentFrame = DTE.Debugger.CurrentStackFrame;

        bool foundTarget = false;
        bool pastCurrent = false;

        StackFrame lastValid = null;
        foreach (StackFrame frame in DTE.Debugger.CurrentThread.StackFrames)
        {
            bool isCurrent = frame == currentFrame;

            if (direction == MoveDirection.Down)
            {
                if (isCurrent)
                {
                    if (lastValid == null)
                    {
                        // No valid frames below this one
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DTE.Debugger.CurrentStackFrame = lastValid;
                        foundTarget = true;
                        break;                      
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (IsValidFrame(frame))
                    {
                        lastValid = frame;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (direction == MoveDirection.Up && pastCurrent)
            {
                if (IsValidFrame(frame))
                {
                    DTE.Debugger.CurrentStackFrame = frame;
                    foundTarget = true;
                    break;
                }               
            }

            if (isCurrent)
            {
                pastCurrent = true;
            }
        }

        if (!foundTarget)
        {
            DTE.StatusBar.Text = "Failed to find valid stack frame in that direction.";
        }
    }

    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        if (DTE.Debugger.CurrentProgram == null)
        {
            DTE.StatusBar.Text = "Debug session not active.";
        }
        else
        {
            // NOTE: Change param 2 to MoveDirection.Up for the up command
            MoveStackIndex(DTE, MoveDirection.Down);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Look in **Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard**. Enter "stack" or "frame" and related menus will appear. It seems that there's no next and previous call-stack frame.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!
But that's exactly what I've said: "...can't even find the menu-command for it."

Comment: @Adrian Aisemberg, I think he is answering your question.  I think he's saying that there is no such shortcut key.

Comment: So how about creating one with a macro?