# Visual Studio debug, jump to end of method, or to calling method

Tags: c#, debugging, stack

I fairly often get to a state in VS (C#) debug breakpoint or exception where I want to exit out of several levels of method to a caller a few levels up the stack.  I can then patch up/retry/etc.

In simple cases I can [1] find the end of the current method, [2] set next statement, and [3] step out.  Then repeat 1/2/3 working my way up the calling stack till I get where I want to be.  However, this is a decided pain ....

Can anyone suggest any automation to help this?  In order of preference ....

1. jump all the way out to where I want to be in one go
2. combine 1/2/3 in a single shortcut I can quickly repeat
3. just automate step 1 (steps 2 and 3 are easy with standard shortcuts).

(I've tried searching, but all the terms I can think of are so generic that I haven't got any useful answers).

Comment: Could you just set a breakpoint to where you wan't to be, then hit F5 to continue execution until that point is hit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/229385/175679

Comment: You can jump to the end of the current method without executing the rest of it but dragging the yellow arrow to the closing brace, but I don't think you can get outside the current method, and I don't think there's a shortcut key for it.

Answer (score 8):

`Shift-F11` steps out of current method.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, that steps out the current method (my step 2).  BUT it tries to execute the intervening statements in the method first; which my step 1 was avoiding.  The bug that caused the initial break often means that these intervening statements will not work either, which is why I want to skip directly to the required point at the levels above.

Answer (score 1):

The debugger does not have a way to set the next statement to execute somewhere other than the current method at the top of the stack.

Comment: Again, thanks, but as with my answer to shift-F11.  That tries to execute all the statements in all call levels of the intervening code until it reaches that point; but I want to avoid executing those statements.